# Proper formatting of cascaded using statements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

I am using C# with Visual Studio. I specify formatting options via EditorConfig. I have been able to get almost everything to work, but I cannot get it to properly format cascaded `using` statements.

Expected result of formatting:

```
public static void Main( string[] args )
{
    using( var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream( "file.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open ) )
        using( var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader( fileStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 ) )
            while( !streamReader.EndOfStream )
                Console.WriteLine( streamReader.ReadLine() );
}
```

Actual result of formatting:

```
public static void Main( string[] args )
{
    using( var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream( "file.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open ) )
    using( var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader( fileStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 ) )
        while( !streamReader.EndOfStream )
            Console.WriteLine( streamReader.ReadLine() );
}
```

Note: this problem persists even if I disable ReSharper.

The question is: what magical incantations do I need to put in my .editorconfig file in order to achieve the "expected" result of formatting instead of the "actual" result of formatting?

I know that this special-case indentation style of cascaded `using` statements is very popular in the dotnet world; nonetheless, it is a special case, and I would rather do without special cases.
The whole point of .editorconfig is to give developers freedom of choice, so where is my freedom to choose that the formatting of my cascaded `using` statements should ***not*** be special-cased?

All those C# programmers who like the special-case formatting of cascaded `using` statements should be glad to know that their perversion can be fulfilled via a construct introduced in C# 8, called ["using declarations"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using) which achieve the same indentation effect without requiring any special-case formatting.

For reference, here is my entire .editorconfig file:

```
# PEARL: Visual Studio offers no special support for the .editorconfig syntax!
#        The "EditorConfig Language Service" extension has not been updated since 2021 and is incompatible with VS2022.
# PEARL: Editing this file using the Visual Studio text editor has been observed to cause Visual Studio to hang!
# PEARL: Do not open this file using the special Visual Studio editor for .editorconfig files!
#        If you do, Visual Studio will garble it, and it will automatically add duplicate entries to it!
# PEARL: The rule for spaces between parentheses in method calls is also applied to compile-time operators
#        such as nameof and typeof even though they are definitely not method calls!

root = true

[*]

indent_style = tab
end_of_line = crlf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
max_line_length = off
indent_size = 4
tab_width = 4

[*.md]

[*.xaml]

[*.cs]

###############################################################################

# PEARL: All spell-checking-related functionality is undocumented. 
#        There exist a few blog posts about it, explaining it in wishy-washy, hand-wavy terms, 
#        but there exists no official reference for it.
# PEARL: The spell-checking dictionary for "en-us" apparently includes the word "Covfefe".
# PEARL: Microsoft uses the term "exclusion" for the custom spell-checking dictionary. 
#        They choose to think of it in terms of exclusion, which is entirely unwarranted.
#        As far as we are concerned, this file has nothing to do with any form of exclusion; 
#        it is just our custom spell-checking dictionary.

# This apparently selects basic spell-checking dictionaries for certain languages. 
# We want en-us only, because "initialise" instead of "initialize" makes me angry.
spelling_languages = en-us

# Specifies where to spell check. Possible values seem to be: strings, identifiers, comments. We want everything.
spelling_checkable_types = strings, identifiers, comments

# Spelling error severity. Possible values seem to be: error, warning, information, hint.
spelling_error_severity = information

# Custom spell-checking file to use. (Either absolute or relative to the root of the solution.)
spelling_exclusion_path = ./exclusion.dic

# The "default exclusion dictionary" for C# contains a ton of nonsense which we definitely do not want.
spelling_use_default_exclusion_dictionary = false
# NOTE: on my machine, the "default exclusion dictionary" for C# is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Editor\SpellChecker\ExclusionDictionaries\csharp.dic

###############################################################################
# Severities:
#   error - Violations appear as build errors and cause builds to fail.
#   warning - Violations appear as build warnings but do not cause builds to fail (unless you have an option set to treat warnings as errors).
#   suggestion - Violations appear as build messages and as suggestions in the Visual Studio IDE.
#   silent - Violations aren't visible to the user.
#   none - Rule is suppressed completely.
#   default - The default severity of the rule is used. The default severities for each .NET release are listed in the roslyn-analyzers repo. In that table, "Disabled" corresponds to none, "Hidden" corresponds to silent, and "Info" corresponds to suggestion.

dotnet_diagnostic.severity = warning

# IDE0047: Remove unnecessary parentheses
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0047.severity = silent

# IDE0063: Use simple 'using' statement
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0063.severity = silent

# IDE0017: Simplify object initialization
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0017.severity = silent

# IDE0058: Expression value is never used
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0058.severity = silent

# CA1051: Do not declare visible instance fields
# Visible instance fields are absolutely fine if immutable.
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1051.severity = none

###############################################################################

dotnet_sort_system_directives_first = true
dotnet_separate_import_directive_groups = false
file_header_template = unset

# These control the use of `.this`
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = false
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property = false
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = false
dotnet_style_qualification_for_event = false

dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members = true
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access = true

# IDE0040 "Accessibility modifiers required"
# Option values:
# - always
# - for_non_interface_members
# - never
# - omit_if_default
# PEARL: It is entirely unclear what the difference is between "never" and "omit_if_default".
#        Observations show that "omit_if_default" is completely useless, and "never" must be used instead.
# PEARL: "warning" must be explicitly specified or else this has no effect.
dotnet_style_require_accessibility_modifiers = never:warning

# IDE0047 "Remove unnecessary parentheses"
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_arithmetic_binary_operators = never_if_unnecessary
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_relational_binary_operators = never_if_unnecessary:silent
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_other_binary_operators = never_if_unnecessary
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_other_operators = never_if_unnecessary

dotnet_style_coalesce_expression = true
dotnet_style_collection_initializer = true:silent
dotnet_style_explicit_tuple_names = true:silent
dotnet_style_namespace_match_folder = true
dotnet_style_null_propagation = true
dotnet_style_object_initializer = true:silent
dotnet_style_operator_placement_when_wrapping = beginning_of_line
dotnet_style_prefer_auto_properties = true
dotnet_style_prefer_compound_assignment = true ;?
dotnet_style_prefer_conditional_expression_over_assignment = true
dotnet_style_prefer_conditional_expression_over_return = false ; # IDE0046 "Convert to conditional expression"
dotnet_style_prefer_foreach_explicit_cast_in_source = when_strongly_typed
dotnet_style_prefer_inferred_anonymous_type_member_names = true:silent
dotnet_style_prefer_inferred_tuple_names = true:silent
dotnet_style_prefer_is_null_check_over_reference_equality_method = true
dotnet_style_prefer_simplified_boolean_expressions = true
dotnet_style_prefer_simplified_interpolation = true

dotnet_style_readonly_field = true

###############################################################################

# Available values for capitalization:
#     pascal_case
#     camel_case
#     first_word_upper
#     all_upper
#     all_lower

# Available values for applicable_kinds:
#     property
#     method
#     field
#     event
#     delegate

dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case_style.capitalization                 = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.word_separator = 

dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_style.capitalization                  = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.word_separator = 

dotnet_naming_rule.camel_case_private_members.severity               = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.camel_case_private_members.symbols                = private_members
dotnet_naming_rule.camel_case_private_members.style                  = camel_case_style
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_members.applicable_kinds               = property, method, field, event
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_members.applicable_accessibilities     = private
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_members.required_modifiers             = *

dotnet_naming_rule.pascal_case_non_private_members.severity          = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.pascal_case_non_private_members.symbols           = private_members
dotnet_naming_rule.pascal_case_non_private_members.style             = camel_case_style
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_private_members.applicable_kinds           = property, method, field, event
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_private_members.applicable_accessibilities = public, protected, internal
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_private_members.required_modifiers         = *

dotnet_style_readonly_field = true
dotnet_code_quality_unused_parameters = all
dotnet_remove_unnecessary_suppression_exclusions = none
dotnet_style_allow_multiple_blank_lines_experimental = false
dotnet_style_allow_statement_immediately_after_block_experimental = true

###############################################################################

csharp_style_var_elsewhere = false
csharp_style_var_for_built_in_types = false
csharp_style_var_when_type_is_apparent = true

# IDE0022: Use expression body for method
csharp_style_expression_bodied_accessors = when_on_single_line
csharp_style_expression_bodied_constructors = false
csharp_style_expression_bodied_indexers = when_on_single_line
csharp_style_expression_bodied_lambdas = true
csharp_style_expression_bodied_local_functions = when_on_single_line
csharp_style_expression_bodied_methods = when_on_single_line
csharp_style_expression_bodied_operators = when_on_single_line
csharp_style_expression_bodied_properties = when_on_single_line

csharp_style_pattern_matching_over_is_with_cast_check = true
csharp_style_pattern_matching_over_as_with_null_check = true
csharp_style_prefer_extended_property_pattern = true
csharp_style_prefer_not_pattern = true
csharp_style_prefer_pattern_matching = true
csharp_style_prefer_switch_expression = true

csharp_style_conditional_delegate_call = true

csharp_prefer_static_local_function = true
csharp_preferred_modifier_order = public, private, protected, internal, file, static, extern, new, virtual, abstract, sealed, override, readonly, unsafe, required, volatile, async
csharp_style_prefer_readonly_struct = true
csharp_style_prefer_readonly_struct_member = true

csharp_prefer_braces = false:warning
csharp_prefer_simple_using_statement = false
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped
csharp_style_prefer_method_group_conversion = true
csharp_style_prefer_top_level_statements = false

csharp_prefer_simple_default_expression = true
csharp_style_deconstructed_variable_declaration = true
csharp_style_implicit_object_creation_when_type_is_apparent = true
csharp_style_inlined_variable_declaration = true
csharp_style_prefer_index_operator = true
csharp_style_prefer_local_over_anonymous_function = true:silent
csharp_style_prefer_null_check_over_type_check = true
csharp_style_prefer_range_operator = true
csharp_style_prefer_tuple_swap = true
csharp_style_prefer_utf8_string_literals = true
csharp_style_throw_expression = true
csharp_style_unused_value_assignment_preference = discard_variable
csharp_style_unused_value_expression_statement_preference = discard_variable

csharp_using_directive_placement = inside_namespace

csharp_style_allow_blank_line_after_colon_in_constructor_initializer_experimental = false
csharp_style_allow_blank_line_after_token_in_arrow_expression_clause_experimental = false
csharp_style_allow_blank_line_after_token_in_conditional_expression_experimental = false
csharp_style_allow_blank_lines_between_consecutive_braces_experimental = false
csharp_style_allow_embedded_statements_on_same_line_experimental = false

###############################################################################

csharp_new_line_before_catch = true
csharp_new_line_before_else = true
csharp_new_line_before_finally = true
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_anonymous_types = true
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_object_initializers = true
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = all
csharp_new_line_between_query_expression_clauses = true

csharp_indent_block_contents = true
csharp_indent_braces = false
csharp_indent_case_contents = true
csharp_indent_case_contents_when_block = false
csharp_indent_labels = flush_left
csharp_indent_switch_labels = true

csharp_space_after_cast = false
csharp_space_after_colon_in_inheritance_clause = true
csharp_space_after_comma = true
csharp_space_after_dot = false
csharp_space_after_keywords_in_control_flow_statements = false
csharp_space_after_semicolon_in_for_statement = true
csharp_space_around_binary_operators = before_and_after
csharp_space_around_declaration_statements = false
csharp_space_before_colon_in_inheritance_clause = true
csharp_space_before_comma = false
csharp_space_before_dot = false
csharp_space_before_open_square_brackets = false
csharp_space_before_semicolon_in_for_statement = false
csharp_space_between_empty_square_brackets = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_empty_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_name_and_opening_parenthesis = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_parameter_list_parentheses = true
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_empty_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_name_and_open_parenthesis = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_parameter_list_parentheses = true
csharp_space_between_parentheses = control_flow_statements ; possible values: control_flow_statements, type_casts, expressions
csharp_space_between_square_brackets = false

csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks = true
csharp_preserve_single_line_statements = false

# PEARL: This is not about spaces, it is about ***extra*** spaces (i.e. two or more spaces.)
#        Essentially, it can be used to allow tabular code formatting. Which we don't.
csharp_space_around_declaration_statements = false
```

Comment: There probably is no option for this, because it's too unconventional. If your unsatisfied with the provided level of configurability, you could try to open a pull request with your desired changes.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride you are saying that special-case formatting is conventional and ***not*** wanting special-case formatting is too unconventional?

Comment: Yes. Someone long ago thought sequential `using`s without braces should be formatted with identical indentation and that's how it became convention. Even though it conflicts with other formatting conventions.

Comment: There is also the option to use some extension, or write your own, to get your desired formatting. I know Resharper has a fair amount of options with regards to code formatting.

Comment: @JonasH thanks for the suggestion, yes, I know. I have been using ReSharper for years, and I have been happy with it. But my colleagues don't. So I am now trying to get the crappy, clunky, meager few offerings by Microsoft to work so as to achieve some semblance of standardization.

Comment: honestly, that's ... pretty horrid; I don't think many tools are going to help you create that; however, IMO: simple using statements are the way to go here: *zero* indentation or additional braces; for comparison: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQhGADAAQBuAhlGQGYCWANjAMoAusVAtmQLxkAdjADuZDDgB0ASQDykgGLM2nGDwAUAIkYtJ7BO00AacVLmLlAWQgATGJNkAHGIICUAbmLlqtAM6qeACU1O1oBYTEJGXkOLm5gqlD1HRU4kyiAFRgDSQBRQUgbBkEAc0kAVQyFAA4PYhwSAH4yX08CEQALZXV1X34WgPiQmChJBJsAGWKYdVdXMgY+wQh2IQBXJiZXQgBvQjID0wBOXrqCAF8gA==

Comment: @MarcGravell horridness is in the eye of the beholder. This style is consistent.

Comment: @MikeNakis then *subjectively*, yes: I agree that this is consistently horrid on each line :)